# mvn test not working with maven 3.3.9 and java 1.8.0_45

Tags: java-8, maven-3, jpa-2.0, spring-4, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running `mvn clean test` with 
**maven 3.3.9
java 1.8.0_45
 testng 6.8.5
 and my spring version is 4.0.4.RELEASE**
 but getting following error.

> [ERROR]
>   springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(com.inn.app17apr02.db.TestAuditDb)
>   Time elapsed: 1.205 s  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file
>   [/home/ist/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/REPO/app17apr02/app17apr02/1.0/app17apr02/target/classes/applicationContext/application.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index; Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

I have searched a lot and have tried different combinations and permutations but still no success.
Following is my plugin entry in pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>testname</name>
                <value>${project.name} TestNG tests reports</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>org.uncommons.reportng.title</name>
                <value>${project.name} TestNG Report</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>org.uncommons.reportng.stylesheet</name>
                <value>/home/ist/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/REPO/app17apr02/app17apr02/1.0/app17apr02/headstart/artifacts/custom.css</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>org.uncommons.reportng.coverage-report</name>
                <value>https://www.google.co.in</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
        <workingDirectory>target/</workingDirectory>
        <reportsDirectory>/home/ist/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/webapps/REPO/app17apr02/app17apr02/1.0/app17apr02/headstart/sartifacts/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>org.apache.tika:tika-app</classpathDependencyExclude>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
        <forkCount>3</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Please let me know if more information is required.**

 I have tried with different JAP 2.x jars as many answers on SO says it is the issue of JPA jar and also tried different surefire version such as 2.18.x, 2.19.x.

 any help will be appreciated.

Comment: also tried with maven 3.0.3 and 3.5.0 but same result and working fine with maven 2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table#indexes() method was added in the version 2.1, so jar you are using is correct.
There might be some other jar added in classpath which also has @Table annotation such as persistence-api-1.0.jar or some other jar. Check your class path and remove/exclude these jars.

You might need hibernate-entitymanager dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I have already checked that using mvn dependancy:tree there is no other persistence jar on classpath and am using same dependency as above

Comment: Then please try adding hibernate-entitymanager, and check if it works.

Comment: Finally it worked there was openjpa-all jar which was conflicting.